# Why don't vegan::vegdist and vegan::metaMDS produce equivalent results?

Tags: r, ecology, diversity, vegan

This question has been discussed before but the proposed solution (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/459820/170801) is no longer reproducible for some reason. As a refresher - it has been suggested that turning off the autotransform and halfchange options in veganMDS() will allow you to produce identical results whether you are directly entering a community data matrix or distance matrix of it:

```
library('vegan')
data(varespec)

dij <- vegdist(varespec, method = 'bray')

set.seed(1)
ord1 <- metaMDS(varespec, distance = 'bray', k = 2)
set.seed(1)
ord2 <- metaMDS(dij, k = 2)
set.seed(1)
ord3 <- metaMDS(varespec, distance = 'bray', k = 2, autotransform = FALSE, 
                halfchange = FALSE)
```

However, when we run

```
all.equal(scores(ord2, 'sites'), scores(ord3, 'sites'))
```

it no longer produces:

```
[1] TRUE
```

as it did previously, but instead now produces:

```
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.5965117"
```

Can anyone explain what's going on, please? Maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1390/gavin-simpson ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case the sole reason seems to be that in your case model `ord2` uses half-change scaling, but `ord3` does not. This information is returned to you in the brief description of the result (*i.e.* with `print`):

```r
> ord2  # prints a brief description of object ord2
...
Scaling: centring, PC rotation, halfchange scaling 

> ord3
...
Scaling: centring, PC rotation
```

You should not use `all.equal` to assess equality of scores from multivariate analysis: things like scaling and orientation of axes are in general undefined in NMDS. We do fix them with (half-change) scaling and PC rotation. However, direction of PC axes is undefined, and they can change sign. You should use Procrustes rotation to assess the similarity of configurations. This is provided by function `vegan::procrustes`. This would tell you that the configurations are equal:

```r
> procrustes(ord2, ord3)

Call:
procrustes(X = ord2, Y = ord3) 

Procrustes sum of squares:
    0
```

In this case this case differences in scaling are sufficient to explain the differences.